# How to get Distinct on a specific column

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, distinct

I want to get distinct by specific `field(ID)` on the datatable not the whole row how to do that :

My table structure :

```
 ID -- name -- desc
```

Code:

```
DataTable dt = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default)//I want to distinct by id instead
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: so the resulting data table would have only the ID?

Comment: The `id` should already be distinct, that's how primary keys work...

Comment: just group your data by id. I can't figure out anything else to select all data by distinct Id....

Comment: Group By is then the way to go. You have to decide what you want to do with rows where you have multiple times the same ID (aggregate (max, min, avg) / first / last ).

Answer (score 0):

If you meant you want a list of distinct values here is an example:

```
List<Int32> fieldList = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()SELECT Int32.Parse(r["ID"].ToString())).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but you can use `IEqualityComparer` will ignore all lines with same Id

```
DataTable dt = table.AsEnumerable().Distinct(new MyComparer<YourClass>())
               .CopyToDataTable()
```

with :

```
    class MyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : YourClass
    {
        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return x.Id.Equals(y.Id);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```